# Java - paste a given little array into another bigger array at a specified position (or interval)

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, copy

I would like to paste a given little array into another bigger array at a specified position (or interval) in Java:

```
int[] bigger_array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] smaller_array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Does exist a simple Java method (with matlab it's simple) that helps me pasting "smaller_array" for example at position 2 (of the bigger) so that "bigger_array" variable becomes:

```
{ 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Please don't paste methods with a simple "for". I want to know if an optimized method exists.

Comment: So you want to **replace** the array elements in given range (which requires checking is the range not out-of-bounds etc.), not *pasting* it *at* a specified position (which requires doing new array)?

Comment: `int[][] biggerarray = new int[10][1]; biggerarray[0][0] = smallerarray[0]; biggerarray[1][0] = smallerarray[1];`

Comment: @Eel Lee: I think that by "optimized" he meant something like *System.arraycopy* which three people answered and which default to native code. That's pretty optimized IMHO.

Comment: By _optimized_ I mean the same that in Matlab is, working with arrays is faster and suggested whereas "for" are slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

> ```
> public static void arraycopy(
>    Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
> ```
>
> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the
>   specified position, to the specified position of the destination
>   array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source
>   array referenced by src to the destination array referenced by dest.
>   The number of components copied is equal to the length argument. The
>   components at positions `srcPos` through `srcPos+length-1` in the source
>   array are copied into positions `destPos` through `destPos+length-1`,
>   respectively, of the destination array.

Note that the documentation on the System class says (emphasis added):

> Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input,
>   standard output, and error output streams; access to externally
>   defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files
>   and libraries; and a **utility method for quickly copying a portion of
>   an array.**

Here's an exaple and its output:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayCopyDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] bigger_array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] smaller_array = { 1, 2, 3 };
        // start copying from position 1 in source, and into 
        // position 3 of the destination, and copy 2 elements.
        int srcPos = 1, destPos = 3, length = 2;
        System.arraycopy(smaller_array, srcPos, bigger_array, destPos, length );
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( bigger_array ));
    }
}
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To copy the entire array, just use `0` as `srcPos`, and `src.length` as `length` (where `src` is the source array;  in this case, you'd use `smaller_array.length`).

Comment: @madx Thanks for the attention+edit.  I'd actually meant `src.length`, because `src` is the parameter name in the Javadoc, but I can see where confusion could arise.  I've edited the edit to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.arraycopy(...)`. Reusing your example:

```
int[] bigger_array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] smaller_array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

You could do:

```
System.arraycopy(smaller_array, 0, bigger_array, 2, 3 );
```

And you'll end up with your `bigger_array` modified and now containing the `{ 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 }` you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src,
             int srcPos,
             Object dest,
             int destPos,
             int length)
```

> System.arraycopy(smaller_array, from_position, bigger_array, to_position, smaller_array.length);

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
int[] bigger_array = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] smaller_array = { 1, 2, 3 };      
System.arraycopy(smaller_array, 0, bigger_array, 2, 3 );
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bigger_array));
```